# Question regarding Regex and StreamReader

Tags: c#

I am supposed to:

1. To check if the file created exists
2. Read the content inside a premade text file and only extract out the dates
3. Doing a count of the number of matches

The text file is named: test.txt and contains the following info:

```
22 Jan,
Hello,
983shs247,
^*(26308,
27 December,
This is a test,
19 June.
```

The output should be:

```
Date Match,
Please enter file name: test.txt,
File exists!,
The date found is: 22 Jan,
The date found is: 27 December,
The date found is: 19 June,
The number of match is: 3.
```

My code only showed till "Date Match,
Please enter the file name: test.txt,
File exists!,
The number of match is :0.
My regex does not seem to extract the dates. Please assist

```
Console.WriteLine("Date Match");
Console.Write("Please enter the file name: ");
string filename = Console.ReadLine();
string fullname = @"C:\Work\" + filename;
int counter = 0;
if (File.Exists(fullname))
{
    Console.WriteLine("File exists!");
    StreamReader file3 = new StreamReader(fullname);
    String inputdata;
    Regex pattern1 = new Regex(@"\d{2}\s+[Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | December]");
     
    while ((inputdata = file3.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach(Match m in pattern1.Matches(inputdata))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The  date found is :"+inputdata);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The number of match is :"+counter);
    file3.Close();
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I suppose it just runs faster than you can read. Add a `Console-ReadLine()` at the end of your code to determistically terminate the program. Alternativly just use your debugger and ehck that the code actually *is* reached.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Hi, thanks for the reply, the output now shows: Date Match
Please enter the file name: test.txt
File exists!
The number of match is :0

Did i do the regex wrongly?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have already applied the updates but it's still not extracting the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is wrong. Try:

```
Regex pattern1 = new Regex(@"\d{1,2}\s+(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sept?(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember))");
```

[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code, but it's still not extracting the dates, am I missing anything else?

Comment: Using your input data with my Regex finds three matches - `22 Jan`, `27 December`, and `19 June`. Check that the content of the file matches the data from your question. Debug your code and step through it line-by-line to make sure you're reading the correct input.

Comment: It works now. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *parsing* - `DateTime.TryParseExact` - instead of *regular expression* matching, e.g.

```
  using System.Globalization;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  Console.WriteLine("Date Match");
  Console.Write("Please enter the file name: ");
  
  string filename = Console.ReadLine();
  string fullname = Path.Combine(@"C:\Work", filename);

  // Let's get rid of streams and query the file:
  var counter = File
    .ReadLines(fullname) 
    .Count(line => DateTime.TryParseExact(
       line.Trim(' ', '.', ','), 
       new string[] { "d MMM", "d MMMM"}, 
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
       out var date));

  Console.WriteLine($"The number of match is {counter}");
```

If you can have *several* dates in a line, you can exploit *regular expressions* to get crude matches, which you then test by *parsing*:

```
  var counter = File
    .ReadLines(fullname)
    .SelectMany(line => Regex
       .Matches(line, @"\b[0-9]{1,2}\s+\p{L}{3,}\b")
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(match => match.Value)) 
    .Count(line => DateTime.TryParseExact(
       line.Trim(' ', '.', ','), 
       new string[] { "d MMM", "d MMMM"}, 
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
       out var date));
```

Please, note that:

- Parsing doesn't match wrong "dates" like `30 Feb`
- It's very easy to *add new formats*, e.g. `MMM d` for `APR 30`
- If you want to *localize* the routine (e.g. let it speaks Russian) all you have to do is to specify culture: `CultureInfo.GetCulture("ru-Ru")` instead of developing a new regular expression pattern